How to add slices to a MRI image? (interpolation)
I have a MRI image of a brain, made of 25 slices, in NIFTI format (so one file containing the 3D data). I need it to have 30 slices to use a specific medical tool - how can I use interpolation to add intermediate slices (or even just slices at the end) ?
I have seen the Matlab function "interp3" mentionned and I tried with the following code:
[rows,cols,slices] = size('subject.nii')
[x1,y1,z1] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows, 1:slices)
[x2,y2,z2] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows, 0.5:0.5:slices)
out = interp3(x1, y1, z1, 'subject.nii', x2, y2, z2, 'linear', 0)

However, it returns the following error:

Error using griddedInterpolant
Sample values must be of type double or single.
Error in interp3 (line 132)
F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);

How can I fix this?
Or should I use a different function? I have also seen "imresize" in this forum but I can't figure out how to use it...

What are the values of [rows,cols,slices] after that first line?

1, 49, 1 - though I am not sure why...

You're passing a character array (the file name) to size. The actual file name you're using is probably 49 characters long. You probably want to use niftiread to read your file and put the data in a variable. Then use that variable in the two places where you have the file name in your code.

Oh, right, thank you! The code seems to work now, so I guess the next step is for me to figure out how to save the "out" variable in the nifti format - instead of passing more character array around (EDIT: it worked with "niftiwrite")

At the bottom of the documentation page I linked, there's a section titled "See Also"... That may be helpful.

Yes, thank you again for your help

there are different ways to add slices. interpolation is definitely not the easiest.
Firstly, one tool I really like for reading and writing NIfTI files is Tools for NIfTI and ANALYZE image by Jimmi Shen. It may look a bit old-fashioned compared to the built-in matlab function but I think it gives you a bit more control over the header and the pixel data.
If you use that toolbox and do
nii = load_untouch_nii ( '/tmp/MNI152_T1_2mm.nii.gz' ); 

then you will have a struct nii with header field hdr and the image field (the pixels) img. This example image has size 91x109x91, you can use interp to sample it to (say) 100x150x100 points:
[ gx, gy, gz ] = ndgrid ( 1:150, 1:100, 1:100 );                                        
img2 = interp3 ( nii.img, gx, gy, gz, 'nearest' );  

and you can look at the two images:
figure ( 1 ); imagesc ( nii.img ( :, :, 1 ) ); axis equal       
figure ( 2 ); imagesc ( rot90 ( img2 ( :, :, 1 ) ) ); axis equal

you can see that the image itself has not changed - you have just added empty space at the sides. (you could have done this by just expanding the matrix!)
You can also resample your image so that the new image fills the same amount of world space as the old image (in your example only in the z-direction, but x and y is also possible):
[ gx, gy, gz ] = ndgrid ( linspace ( 1, 109, 150 ), linspace ( 1, 91, 100 ), linspace ( 1, 91, 100 ) );
img3 = interp3 ( double ( nii.img ), gx, gy, gz, 'linear' );
figure ( 3 ); imagesc ( rot90 ( img3 ( :, :, 1 ) ) ); axis equal

The reason that img3 may not be such a good idea is that you have changed the world-size of the image: the original field nii.hdr has a field pixdim which gives the spacing of every point (in this case it is 2x2x2 mm³). But now that you compress the same world-space into more points, their spacing has decreased; you now need to change the header of your resampled file to reflect that (i.e., the world size of your pixels needs to be smaller).
Long story short, img2 really has slices added to it, img3 has been spread over more slices.
